# Why is there different Pedaling in different editions of Chopin's op 57?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, keyboard-pedals, chopin, editions

In seeking the score for this piece, I came across 2 frequent editions: one that shows to use the pedal for half the bar, the other to use 2 bursts of pedal

Which pedaling is correct?

Comment: Have you checked out the [IMSLP page](https://imslp.org/wiki/Berceuse,_Op.57_(Chopin,_Frédéric)) for this piece?  It has a manuscript, first edition, and many other versions.

Comment: Which editions are these?

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

The edition shown in the second video is correct insofar as it matches Chopin's hand-written copy.

---

#### The source editions

**Video #1**

The edition used in the first video I am not able to identify. It's not any of the editions currently on IMSLP, and several Google searches, including image searches for different parts of the score, did not turn it up.

**Video #2**

This is the Peters *Sämtliche Pianoforte-Werke, Band X: Berceuse, Barcarolle, etc.* edited by Herrmann Scholtz, which can be found on IMSLP.

#### Chopin's original

There is an autograph copy, available on IMSLP, that was used for the first German edition. It clearly shows pedaling at the half-measure.

[image: Chopin, Op. 57, autograph mm. 1-4]

Almost every edition on IMSLP follows this autograph. The variations are the French first edition — the piece's first publication, the German came next — and editions clearly based on the French edition. These are wrong, based on the evidence of the autograph.

#### Why the variation

The Video #2 edition — the Scholtz — correctly follows Chopin's autograph. The Video #1 edition, however, seems to follow neither the French nor German editions. The French edition has twice-per-measure pedaling in mm. 13–14, for example; whereas, the Video #1 version maintains the first-half-of-the-measure pedaling in those measures. The departure from the autograph/German editions is obvious from the first measure.

This leaves three possibilities.

1. The Video #1 edition is just sloppy and poorly written, based on the French edition.
2. The Video #1 edition is based on the French edition, but the editor figured that the French edition's departures from first-half-of-the-measure pedaling (e.g., mm. 13–14) were errors.
3. The edition is an editorial performance edition, reflecting not Chopin's "urtext" (which may or may not have been available to the editor), but rather reflecting how the editor felt the piece was best performed.

Comment: If we ignore the authority of each source, which version is "musically correct", and why?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Are you suggesting ignoring the authority even of Chopin's hand-written copy?

Comment: "these are wrong based i'on the evidence of the autograph":the first edition could have been based on another autograph that has not survived.

Comment: Your answer so far is excellent research and certainly useful.  But manuscripts can have mistakes, and musically informed "improvements" can sometimes be made.  I don't think your answer has yet gone to *why* (musically) the pedalling change might have been made, and whether it makes the piece any "better" or "worse".  I think "Which version is 'musically correct?'" is more interesting.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Your point is perfectly valid, but well beyond the scope of the question. The question simply asks why there are different editions, and I've covered the possibilities: mistakes or different interpretations. Whether one interpretation is more valid than another is a separate question. One worth asking, but separate, and requiring a very different, and much deeper, and potentially highly subjective, kind of analysis. I would welcome the opportunity to consider it, but it's too far beyond the scope here.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace "which version is musically correct" is just a matter of opinion.  It's entirely possible that Chopin wrote the piece out more than once and applied different pedal indications in different copies.  It's also possible that the image here shows the only autograph manuscript, but even still, it's possible that the first edition was prepared with Chopin's participation and is therefore authoritative.  If the composer himself had different opinions at different times, there's not much we can do to say which is "correct."

Comment: @phoog - We can at least split by edition - e.g. versions of Bernstein's *Candide* are quite drastically different, as are versions of Liszt's Csardas Macabre. However, we can validly say which portions of Bernstein's 2nd version of *Candide* are not in his 1st, and which portions of the urtext version of Liszt's Csardas Macabre are taken out of other editions.

Comment: @Dekkadeci ok, but that's a bit excessive in this case, don't you think?  It's just a few pedal markings.

Answer (score 0):

Often an editor will add his own fingering, phrasing or pedalling into a score which doesn't make it right or good.  It just is.